# SQL Server ExpressMaint use account (id/pw)

Tags: sql-server

I am using below batch command for ExpressMaint. I know it has worked with a Windows account.

When I disable the Windows account on the SQL Server instance, it doesn't work correctly.

```
D:\ExpressMaint\ExpressMaint.exe -S . -D TEST -T CHECKDB -R D:\ExpressMaint\Report -RU WEEKS -RV 4
```

I get this message

> Failed to connect to server ..
> Login failed for user 'DPY\gw.lee'. Reason: The account is disabled.
>
> ExpressMaint finished unsuccessfully at 2020-03-09 오후 3:47:32 with Return Code(-3)

Can I have option for specifying ID/PW of SQL Server instance?

Comment: did you try using the -help or other command line arguments that can be listed from the exe, which should be a good option to checkout.

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlmaint-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) - it seems pretty obvious.